# Sort and rearrange JSON array based on entries

Tags: python, list, numpy, sorting

I'm a total python newbie but still search for an elegant way to solve the following task. I already searched through the forum, but I only found very particular solutions for other list problems.

I'm trying to analyze, sort and rearrange an JSON array in python. But I haven't found a working solution so far to sort the list from the lowest to the highest value entries.

this is my example list:

```
 [{'path': 'file_abc.wav', 'val': [0.49]}, 
  {'path': 'file_dfg.wav', 'val': [0.0]}, 
  {'path': 'file_ejh.wav', 'val': [1.0]}]
```

I'd like to rearrange the input list the according to its value beginning from the lowest up to the highest:

```
[{'path_old': 'file_dfg.wav', 'val': [0.0]}, 
 {'path_old': 'file_abc.wav', 'val': [0.49]}, 
 {'path_old': 'file_ejh.wav', 'val': [1.0]}]
```

I would be very pleased if anybody could give me a hint how to solve this in a good way!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sorted(your_list, key=lambda x:x['val'][0])
```

`sorted` accepts an argument(`key`) and if you set it, it will sort that iterable based on that.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for your fast reply! Finally I understand the key argument!

Comment: Your welcome @ChrisLos. please consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @ChrisLos Yes, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [
  {'path': 'file_abc.wav', 'val': [0.49]}, 
  {'path': 'file_dfg.wav', 'val': [0.0]}, 
  {'path': 'file_ejh.wav', 'val': [1.0]}
]
print(sorted(lst, key=lambda d: d['val'][0]))
```

This prints:

```
[
  {'path': 'file_dfg.wav', 'val': [0.0]}, 
  {'path': 'file_abc.wav', 'val': [0.49]}, 
  {'path': 'file_ejh.wav', 'val': [1.0]}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

### If you dont to create a new list then you can also use `lst.sort(key = lambda function)`

```
aa =  [{'path': 'file_abc.wav', 'val': [0.49]}, 
  {'path': 'file_dfg.wav', 'val': [0.0]}, 
  {'path': 'file_ejh.wav', 'val': [1.0]}]


aa.sort(key = lambda x:x['val'])
print (aa)

#OUTPUT:
#[{'path': 'file_dfg.wav', 'val': [0.0]}, {'path': 'file_abc.wav', 'val': [0.49]}, {'path': 'file_ejh.wav', 'val': [1.0]}]
```